# Optimising Kivy/KivyMD ScreenManager

Tags: python, optimization, memory, kivy, kivymd

I am currently working on a project with KivyMD which uses multiple screens; here is a basic overview of the structure I currently have, which is working and runs:

```
src/
    Frontend/
        gui.kv -> This has the root ScreenManager used in the app
        GUI/ -> This is where the KV files are stored for each screen
            screen1.kv
            screen2.kv etc.
        screen1.py
        screen2.py etc. -> The python files for each screen
        frontend.py -> This contains the main App class
    main.py -> This is the main 'executable' which imports the main App and calls app.run()
```

Currently, I have the root ScreenManager (in the gui.kv file) like so:

```
ScreenManager:
    screen1
    screen2
    etc.
```

and then in the main app, the build() function loads the gui.kv file (And therefore the ScreenManager)

This allows the app and each screen to call every other screen, which works fine, however leads to two issues: 1) Slow load time on launch, as all of the screens are loaded at the launch of the app; and 2) High memory usage, as I understand Kivy will keep all the loaded screens in memory.

My app currently uses about 350-450MB of RAM straight after loading, with about 4 screens, which is excessive, especially as around 5 more screens and lots more code are needed.  I have checked and my own code is adding a minimal amount of memory overhead.  It also takes around 17 seconds to launch, whereas loading only one screen reduces this to around 5.  I can see the bulk of this time is coming from the build() function.

Is there a way to structure things so that each screen is only loaded into the screen manager when it is required?  For example, it currently launches into a login screen which then leads to a home screen (which are all loaded at launch); is there a way to only have the login screen load on launch, and then when the home screen is called, remove the login screen from memory and load the home screen etc.?

Alternatively, is there a way to perhaps speed up the load time; say loading the first screen and then loading subsequent screens once initialized?

I have tried a few different structures but cannot seem to work it out!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think the file structure has much (if any) effect on load time. You can definitely just build and load the first `Screen` that your `App` displays, then just build and load new `Screens` as they are needed. If memory is a problem, you can also remove any `Screen` that will not be used again, or even create/remove `Screens` as they are needed. Of course, all this is a trade-off of initial load time vs memory vs responsiveness of the `App`. Another option is to just display a `Please Wait` popup while the rest of the `Screens` are loaded.

Comment: Hi @JohnAnderson, thanks for your comments.  I am aware that I should be able to build and load Screens as required; it's the implementation with ScreenManager of this which has me confused, such as adding a new screen within python.

Comment: You can use `add_widget()` method of `ScreenManager` to add new `Screens` to the `ScreenManager`. You can also use `switch_to()` to add and display a `Screen`, and `has_screen()` to determine if a `Screen` is already loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I had a go at loading/dismissing screens but found memory usage was in fact worse, however I've managed to reformat the screen loading at launch so it's now much smoother.  Thanks for your help @JohnAnderson